# Convert the ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco model with tensorflow_js

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow

I want to build an app with javascript which integrates object-detection. For this, I wanna use the ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco model and use it in tensorflow.
However this line of code:

`C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\Scripts\tensorflowjs_converter  --input_format=tf_saved_model --output_node_names='image_tensor, detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections' \saved_model\saved_model \saved_model\web_model`

does not work. It gives me file not found error, but the file is actually there unless I'm very dump and turned back into computer beginner.

`OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: \saved_model\saved_model`

[image]

Also, I'm not quite sure about the output node names but this is secondary.

Thanks for support, hopefully I'm not totally dump :)

Comment: Have you solved it out yet?

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you are using an absolute path instead of a relative path.

On mac or linux, if you are in the directory that contains the downloaded unzipped model, you would run a command of that type :

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_saved_model --output_node_names='detection_boxes,detection_classes,detection_scores,num_detections' --saved_model_tags=serve ./ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco/saved_model ./ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco/web_model
```

From what i can see you are on Windows.
If you are running your command from the directory that contains the saved_model folder, you should run the following command :

```
C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\Scripts\tensorflowjs_converter  --input_format=tf_saved_model --output_node_names='image_tensor, detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections' .\saved_model\saved_model .\saved_model\web_model
```